# How to control appearance of ':' in time zone offset when parsing/formatting Datetime

Tags: .net, datetime, timezone

I'm working with a protocol that may optionally include a time zone offset when specifying datetime information.  My code is written in C# and we are using the 4.0 .NET runtime.  I see that there is a [formatting option "zzz"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for including timezone information when parsing and formatting, however, it appears that the colon (:) is fixed.  For instance, a Datetime formatted with the custom format string (yyyyMMddHHmmsszzz) might appear as:

**20100309101530-05:00**

The protocol I am working with does not include the colon in the timezone offset.  This protocol will format datetimes, and expect them to be formatted as:

**20100309101530-0500**

Is there a way to control the appearance of the colon when parsing or formatting datetime with a custom formatter that includes the timezone offset?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Doesn't look like there is anything built-in (you can use `zz`, but that leaves out the minutes).

You can roll your own by instantiating a [`DateTimeFormatInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx), setting `TimeSeparator` to `string.Empty` and using that as the `IFormatProvider` when calling `DateTime.ToString` (and make the call explicit, if it is not already).

But frankly, using [`Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx) to remove the unwanted `:` from the default return value is so much easier.

Comment: According .NET engineers `DateTimeFormatInfo.TimeSeparator` would not affect time zone https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/42520#issuecomment-552227847

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same problem, ended up using an extension

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{        
    public static String ToSomeFormat(this DateTimeOffset dateTime)
    {
        return dateTime.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmsszzz").Replace(":", "");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using it in a place where it doesn't make sense to use replace or extend (for example something that might want to output as `-05:00` with a colon when passed as `zzz`) and the minutes don't matter you could fake it with `zz00`.

```
var date = new DateTimeOffset(2008, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0, new TimeSpan(-5, 0, 0));
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss(zz00)"));
// outputs 2008-08-01-00:00:00(-0500)
```

Comment: Just be wary of offsets that don't fall on the hour: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/time-zones-interesting.html

Answer (score 2):

I had exact same [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/42520), trying to format/parse time zone in the format like `+0730`.

**Formatting** DateTime with `zzz` will *always* output time offset in `hh:mm` format.
Initially I though that it should be possible to get custom format by overriding `DateTimeFormatInfo.TimeSeparator` (`:` by default), but in case of the time zone it's hardcoded in [`System.DateTimeFormat.FormatCustomizedTimeZone`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/465da74726664728b690ce4d0086d56f59187a1f/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Globalization/DateTimeFormat.cs#L824):

```
// 'zzz*' or longer format e.g "-07:30"
result.AppendFormat(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, ":{0:00}", offset.Minutes);
```

Here's [response](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/42520#issuecomment-552227847) of engineer working on .NET:

> The zzz is formatted as a time span and not regular DateTime. It has been decided since day one to use the standard format for the formatting the time zone part in the date/time objects. So, it is intentional always using : as a separator for the formatting the time span part. I understand you can argue this not the correct decision, but we cannot change this now as the scope of breaking will be very big as many people depend on parsing the dates assuming this format. You can still workaround this issue by replacing : with the desired separator you want.

So the here's my version of how to custom formatting of the timezone:

```
    var utcOffset = dateTime.Kind == DateTimeKind.Utc? TimeSpan.Zero : TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(dateTime);
    var utcOffsetSrt = (utcOffset < TimeSpan.Zero ? "-" : "+") + utcOffset.ToString("hhmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    var dateTimeStr = dateTime.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    var result = dateTimeStr + utcOffsetSrt;
```

**Parsing** however works out of the box with `zzz` for empty separator:

```
var result = DateTime.ParseExact("+0000", "zzz", customInvariantCulture);
var resultOffset = TimeZoneInfo.Utc.GetUtcOffset(result.ToUniversalTime());
Assert.AreEqual(offset, resultOffset);
```

Looking into [`System.DateTimeParse.ParseTimeZoneOffset`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/5bc7c43f61842f19247cef40ba88f7fb395b956d/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Globalization/DateTimeParse.cs#L3268):

```
if (str.Match(":"))
{
    // Found ':'
    if (!ParseDigits(ref str, 2, out minuteOffset))
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

So `zzz` will work only if you have no delimiter or when it's `:`.

Comment: This is the most comprehensive answer, as it looked at formatting AND parsing. Thank you!