# How can I parse this date?

Tags: c#, datetime

I think I miss a Culture Info? (which I don't know what it is).
I get this date from a json:

```
<created_at>Tue Jul 16 07:56:04 +0000 2013</created_at>
```

but if I try:

```
var CreatedAt = DateTime.ParseExact((string)x["created_at"], "yyyy-MM-dd", null)
```

I get a `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.` exception. What should I use?

Comment: What have you tried? You must be able to figure something out using the [examples given here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx). If the colon (`:`) absence is confusing for the `zzzz` format, try [creating your own `DateTimeFormatInfo`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247876/how-to-control-appearance-of-in-time-zone-offset-when-parsing-formatting-dat).

Comment: Your `ParseExact` is expecting a value in the format `yyyy-MM-dd`. That isn't even *slightly* the same as the format you're providing, is it?

Comment: Reading documentation is no fun. StackOverflow, sudo make me the correct pattern format.

Comment: Please, please, please, stop programming by accident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this pattern to match just the date:

```
ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy
```

As in

```
var input = "Tue Jul 16 07:56:04 +0000 2013";
var pattern = "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy"
var result = DateTime.ParseExact(input, pattern, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(result.ToUniversalTime()); // 7/16/2013 7:56:04 AM
```

Or this to match the date *and* the XML tags around it:

```
'<created_at>'ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy'</created_at>'
```

As in

```
var input = "<created_at>Tue Jul 16 07:56:04 +0000 2013</created_at>";
var pattern = "'<created_at>'ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy'</created_at>'";
var result = DateTime.ParseExact(input, pattern, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(result.ToUniversalTime()); // 7/16/2013 7:56:04 AM
```

**Further Reading**

- [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: I get the same message!

Comment: With date Mon Jul 15 16:06:09 +0000 2013 it doesnt work! (which have the same pattern)

Comment: @markzzz Yes it does. I've updated it since my original posting to use `HH` (24-hour time) rather than `hh` (12-hour time).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
DateTime.ParseExact((string)x["created_at"], "ddd MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzzz yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Note: If your string doesn't match exactly (see, `Parse`**Exact**) the format you provide.. then it won't work.

Comment: +1 for invariant culture

Comment: This seems to works perfect! But If I put null instead of CultureInfo.InvariantCulture I get the same error message...

Comment: @markzzz so clearly the culture your machine runs under doesn't implicitly understand the format being passed in. When you pass `null` for `IFormatProvider` the `Parse` method uses the current culture format of the machine, I am running under UK culture so `null` works fine for me, if your format is culture *independent* then you should use `InvariantCulture`.

Comment: There is anyway a problem. I get this error with that date: `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. - Mon Jul 15 16:06:09 +0000 2013`

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime.ParseExact("Tue Jul 16 07:56:04 +0000 2013", 
                    "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy", 
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/Jj1E2e)

Note that `HH` is 24hour format as opposed to `hh`

Answer (score 0):

Well that's because `ParseExact` means you are telling the method your date is in that *exact* format (which clearly it's not).

The date in question does appear to be a quite specific format, you would need to do something like:

```
DateTime.ParseExact((string)x["created_at"], "ddd MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzzz yyyy", null);
```

Based on your comments it appears your application is running under a culture which doesn't understand the date/time format provided - passing `null` will implicitly use the current culture (which is generally the culture of the machine). In that case you need to pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` instead of `null`, reason being so the string can be parsed independent of any local rules/localisations which are enforced during the parsing i.e.

```
DateTime.ParseExact((string)x["created_at"], "ddd MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzzz yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```