# C# Format specific Datetime to string

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, string-formatting, datetime-format

I need to format current DateTime like this:

`Mon, 18 Mar 2019 15:10:24 +0000`

but i can't find the specific Format string in C#. The documentation required this string format:

`EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss O`

I try :
`DateTime.Now.ToString("r")` but it returns `GMT` instead of `+0000` part.
`DateTime.Now.ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz")` but it returns `+02:00` instead of `+0200` part.

How can i format the date?

Comment: There is no question here!

Comment: @phuzi I think it boils down to "How to format DateTime Offset as '<sign>HHmm' instead of '<sign>HH:mm'"?

Comment: @phuzi _"but it returns +02:00 instead of +0200 part."_ makes it pretty clear _to me_ but I could be mistaken.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247876/how-to-control-appearance-of-in-time-zone-offset-when-parsing-formatting-dat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Now;

d.ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zz00")
```

Comment: As far as I see it's possible that the minutes part could be uneven 00 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_time_offsets).

I would recommend this hack:

DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
string.Concat( d.ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss "), d.ToString("zzz").Remove(3,1))